# How can I close the help bar in question details?

Tags: bug

I can' see my text, on the top becouse, this bar there.
Is that possible hide somehow?
Screenshot from the problem:
[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/2rww8wh.png]

Comment: Can you provide any steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: What browser are you on?

Comment: Chrome 39.0.2171.95 m.

Comment: And I just open a question.
This problem is there every stack site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you have to do is click the little question mark icon at the very right of the formatting options (above the yellow help bar). That toggles the help bar on/off.

I'm pretty sure, though, that the help bar is supposed to shift the textarea down far enough so that the help bar doesn't overlap it. Hopefully they'll get that fixed before pushing the new design to Stack Overflow (the current design here on Meta is new and they released it here to test and make sure they got all the bugs flushed out).